# Spring inbound channel adapter - how to auto delete folders and files older than 10 days

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

**Integration.xml** - this will take all files in the directory

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="delFiles" channel="delFiles" 
        directory="C:/abc/abc" use-watch-service="true" prevent-duplicates="false" auto-startup="true"
            watch-events="CREATE,MODIFY">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
        <int-file:nio-locker/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I need to delete all files older than 10 days in that folder and sub folder. Can some one pls help?

**Listener**

```
@Transformer(inputChannel="delFiles")
    public JobLaunchRequest deleteJob(Message<File> message) throws IOException {
        Long timeStamp = message.getHeaders().getTimestamp();
        return JobHandler.deleteJob(message.getPayload(), jobRepository, fileProcessor, timeStamp);
    }
```

**Handler**

```
public static JobLaunchRequest deleteJob(File file, JobRepository jobRepository, Job fileProcessor, Long timeStamp) throws IOException {

//Is there a way in spring integration whether I can check this easily?
//How to check for folder and subfolders?
// This will check for files once it's dropped.
// How to run this job daily to check the file's age and delete?

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` responsibility. This one is really about  polling files from the directory according filtering setting you provide.

If you are not interested in old files, you can implement a custom `FileListFilter` to skip files which are really so old.

If you still would like to delete those old files as some application functionality, you need to take a look into some other solution, something like `@Scheduled` method it iterate through files in that dir and remove them, e.g. once a day let's say at midnight.

You also can just remove processed files in the and of your logic. Since you use `prevent-duplicates="false"`, you are going to poll the same file again and again.

To perform directory clean up you don't need Spring Integration:

```
public void recursiveDelete(File file) {
    if (file != null && file.exists()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File fyle : files) {
                if (fyle.isDirectory()) {
                    recursiveDelete(fyle);
                }
                else {
                    if (fyle.lastModified() > 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
                        fyle.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(You might to improve this function a bit: haven't tested...)

Comment: I use spring integration because my application instances are mounted on NFS. So, I should use spring integration right?

Comment: That's not related. In the and it is just Spring application and you deal with the `java.io.File`. I don't see reason to overhead such a task with Spring Integration and Spring Batch. Those are slightly for different tasks. You can, of course, but we would need to spend more time to think about an unusual solution for you...